# Apache SSL certificate is not working without error

Tags: apache, ssl

I want to put a ssl certificate which was generated today on a website but it doesn't work. The secured page is not loading, but the insecure one works.  This is my conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example
        <Directory /var/www/example>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/example-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/example-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>


        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example
        <Directory /var/www/example>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /root/certs/example.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/XXX.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/certs/example.crt


ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>
```

It is weird that I don't have errors in ssl_error_log:

```
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.266922 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 12429] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'example.com:443'
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267378 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267430 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 12429] AH01914: Configuring server example.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267738 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(886): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267751 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(406): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267762 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(933): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267939 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_util_ssl.c(508): AH02412: [example.com:443] Cert matches for name 'example.com' [subject: CN=example.com / issuer: CN=RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US / serial: example / notbefore: Apr  2 00:00:00 2021 GMT / notafter: May  3 23:59:59 2022 GMT]
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.267957 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(988): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.310426 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 12429] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'example.com:443'
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.310726 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.310770 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 12429] AH01914: Configuring server example.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.310983 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(886): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.310994 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(406): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.311002 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(933): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.311108 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_util_ssl.c(508): AH02412: [example.com:443] Cert matches for name 'example.com' [subject: CN=example.com / issuer: CN=RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US / serial: XXX / notbefore: Apr  2 00:00:00 2021 GMT / notafter: May  3 23:59:59 2022 GMT]
[Fri Apr 02 22:33:55.311117 2021] [ssl:debug] [pid 12429] ssl_engine_init.c(988): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
```

```
[root@vps httpd]# curl https: //xxx.com
curl: (7) Failed connect to xxx.com:443; Connection refused
```

The port is open is firewall.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you enabled the site with a2ensite? is mod_ssl installed? do you have Listen 443 in your config?

Comment: Uhhhh. yes . listen 443 was forgotten  . thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

Other than what Ryan wrote which is absolutely corrent, you should fix (or remove)

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/certs/example.crt
```

If you want to fix it, you shouldn't use the certificate here but the chain which means the certificate used to sign your csr. The chain may or may not include the root: I personally never include the root.

On a side note, i suggest you to move certificates outside root home directory: you can create a sub-folder in apache root directory (/etc/{apache2,httpd}/certs) for example.